# Upgrading to Spring Boot 3/ JDK 17/ Spring 6 - JAXB conflict issue IllegalAnnotationsException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jaxb, java-17

We are upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.0, JDK 17 and Spring/ Spring Security 6. The issue is with JAXB on application startup. Here is the **UPDATED** error message on the logs:

**EDIT2 **

Have jakarta.xml.bind and jaxb-runtime dependencies in the pom, but it's still looking for javax.xml.bind.*, but not sure where it's trying to reference it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Jaxb2Marshaller' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1441)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:769)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator$5.run(ReflectionNavigator.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator$5.run(ReflectionNavigator.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionNavigator.java:295)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionNavigator.java:34)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.collectGetterSetters(ClassInfoImpl.java:1036)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findGetterSetterProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:949)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:299)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1115)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:58)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:322)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:392)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:349)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:260)
    at abc.as.server.binding.JAXB2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromContextPath(JAXB2Marshaller.java:101)
    at abc.as.server.binding.JAXB2Marshaller.createJaxbContext(JAXB2Marshaller.java:93)
    at abc.as.server.binding.JAXB2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(JAXB2Marshaller.java:81)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 79 more
```

**EDIT**

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>abc.as.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>as-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        ...
        <jacoco.version>0.8.10</jacoco.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.18.0</log4j2.version>
        <tomcat.version>10.1.13</tomcat.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.9.0</junit-jupiter.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion> 
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                </exclusion> 
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion> 
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
             <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Don't remove for now - revisit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add - check how to use this instead -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Add -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- database support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
            <version>19.8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-engine-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
          </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>openws</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                     <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                     <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>  
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>abc.ts</groupId>
            <artifactId>app.common</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>           
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>abc.ts</groupId>
            <artifactId>oidc.common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
            <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                
        <!-- Apache CXF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logstash Patterns for JSON output -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
          <version>7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- vulnerability fixes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-provider-redis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SLF4J API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        ...
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        ...
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        ...
    </pluginRepositories>
    
    <build>
        ...     
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you share the `pom.xml` file and the bean definition please ? There no additionnal info in the stacktrace (is it complete here ?)?

Comment: Sure will do...it's a big file...will post relevant parts.... Thanks so much @LaurentSchoelens

Comment: EDIT: Interestingly, this change: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.4</version>
            <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
              <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>  causes the application to terminate as soon as started with no errors

Comment: Now got this error while debug: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from SpringSecurity 6, the cas client changed from `org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core` to `org.apereo.cas.client:cas-client-core`, the previous one was based on Spring5 and didn't get the upgrade

Just remove the problematic dependency if using spring-security-cas or replace with the following (shown latest release here) :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also fix imports to the new packages (should be drop-in, just replace `jasig` by `apereo` I guess

** EDIT **

After deeper analysis of your configuration, I spotted old imports of jaxb2 api related dependencies :

The following `javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1` should be changed to

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You should also update the `jaxws-rt` and `jaxws-ri` to latest 4.0.x version (4.0.2)

By doing so, you'll remove latest references to jaxb-api 2.3.x and jaxb-runtime 2.3.x

Comment: Thanks so much. Before making the changes you proposed, i made some progress and will edit and post the most recent error message I get. Also made the change you proposed, but that didnt help with this error :(

Comment: Added additional suggestion based on deeper analysis of the `pom.xml`

Comment: Will mark this as correct, but the issue was internal